# Parsing MS specific html tags in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

When trying to parse an email sent using MS Outlook, I want to be able to strip the annoying Microsoft XML tags that it has added. One such example is the `o:p` tag. When trying to use Python's BeautifulSoup to parse an email as HTML, it can't seem to find these specialty tags.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

textToParse = """
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Something to parse</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><o:p>This should go</o:p>Paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(textToParse, "html5lib")

body = soup.find('body')

for otag in body.find_all('o'):
  print(otag)

for otag in body.find_all('o:p'):
  print(otag)
```

This will output no text to the console, but if I switched the `find_all` call to search for `p` then it would output the `p` node as expected.

How come these custom tags do not seem to work?

Comment: It's a namespace issue. Other similar questions suggest `soup.find('o:p')` ought to work – can you check that?

Comment: This does work, thank you - how come `find` and `find_all` work differently? And better yet, how can I get the behaviour of `find_all` since that is ultimately what I need?

Comment: There is definitely something fishy going on with the HTML parser. See my answer – found through (admittedly quite random) attempts following various related questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a namespace issue. Apparently, BeautifulSoup does not consider custom namespaces valid when parsed with `"html5lib"`.

You can work around this with a regular expression, which – strangely – *does* work correctly!

```
print (soup.find_all(re.compile('o:p')))
>>> [<o:p>This should go</o:p>]
```

but the "proper" solution is to change the parser to `"lxml-xml"` and introducing `o:` as a valid namespace.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

textToParse = """
<html xmlns:o='dummy_url'>
  <head>
    <title>Something to parse</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><o:p>This should go</o:p>Paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(textToParse, "lxml-xml")

body = soup.find('body')

print ('this should find nothing')
for otag in body.find_all('o'):
  print(otag)

print ('this should find o:p')
for otag in body.find_all('o:p'):
  print(otag)

>>>
this should find nothing
this should find o:p
<o:p>This should go</o:p>
```